# Nuclear disintegration of charge

Tags: nuclear-physics

If an atom is totally disintegrated or converted into energy then what happens to charges. 
Or an electron is converted into energy then what happen to charge

Comment: An electron does not convert to energy, just like that. Thank god. Charge is always conserved.

Comment: Charge is conserved I know but things like quark also exist if you know

Comment: If you know that charge is conserved, then I don't understand your question. And why you mention quarks now, I do not understand either.

Comment: By "conversion into energy" you probably mean annihilation. That can only be done with antiparticles which have opposite charge. The opposite charges cancel, so the total charge is conserved. Electron and positron turn into photons, the total charge is zero before and also after the interaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are precise rules for the creation or destruction of particles. First of all, we must distinguish between [elementary particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle) and composite particles. An atom is composed of electrons, protons and neutrons and these last two are composed of up and down quarks in different proportions, so we should analyse what happens to these particles instead of the whole atom.

Another important point is to distinguish between bosons and fermions. Every particle has a fundamental property called [spin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_(physics)). Moreover, any kind of particle can have only integer values (0, 1, 2, ...), in which case it's called a boson, or half-integer values (1/2, 3/2, 5/2, ...), in which case it's called a fermion. Spin can increase or decrease only by integer intervals, so fermions can't become bosons and vice versa.

Electrons, neutrinos (called together leptons) and quarks are always fermions, while photons are always bosons. Other particles exist, you can find them in the first image of the first link above, but every one of them is either a fermion or a boson. Bosons can be created and destroyed quite easily (think for example about creation and absorption of light), while fermions require some special conditions.

Finally, you must remember that the charge is always conserved. If you want to destroy a particle, you have to somehow take away its charge. That's where [antimatter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimatter) comes in. An antiparticle has exactly the same property of its counterpart, but an opposite charge. For example the electon has charge -1, to its antiparticle, the positron, has charge +1. The mass however is the same for both particles. Now a system containing an electron and a positron has a total charge of 0 and indeed if you bring them into contact they will annihilate and turn into two photons (usually) emitted back to back.

Research is still ongoing for most, if not all, of the topics I touched, so consider this answer as a first introduction in the world of nuclear physics. The informations I gave you are accurate enough to start with, but if you want to go deeper you need more.

**Edit:** A few specifications about the electron-positron annihilation. The process is more complicated than the one I described. Electron and positron have opposite charges and thus attract each other. When they come near enough, there is a probability, depending on various factors such as the angle of incidence, that the two particles will "disappear" and turn into photons. As far as I know there is no internal mechanism in this process: One moment you see an electron and a positron, the following one you see two photons.

You can also produce particles from photons, but the process isn't exactly the opposite of the one described above, since it's not clear how can two photons hit each other. The process is called [pair production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production) and requires a photon with enough energy to produce both a particle and its antiparticle.

Comment: How electrons and positrons combine to give photons . Then ( if possible ) photons can be converted back into them charge

Comment: @AjayVijay I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> If an atom is totally disintegrated or converted into energy then what happens to charges.

Atoms cannot totally disintegrate at the energies available in a  lab, and **charge is always conserved**. Nuclei of the atoms can decay, part of their mass turning into energy and most of it to new nuclei, but charge is conserved. A proton meeting an electron at appropriate energetic conditions can turn into a neutron, the + and -charge adding to 0 . Neutron stars are mainly composed out of neutrons , the positive and negative charges adding to zero mainly.

> Or an electron is converted into energy then what happen to charge

An electron  cannot be converted into energy, charge conservation is an unbroken law; it can annihilate with a positron, and depending on the energy [a lot of particles may come out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_Electron%E2%80%93Positron_Collider), the sum of all produced  charges  zero. Various other conservation laws also hold in the production of particles with e+e- annihilation at the same time.